# URL Masking with htaccess 2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have the following url:

```
http://site/testing/mypage.php?PropertyBuyRent=sell&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=US&Price=
```

I have htaccess that checks that if there is something in the variable country, it changes the url like this:

```
http://site/testing/mypage.php/TimeshareForSale/US
```

My htaccess file is below:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(testing/mypage\.php)\?PropertyBuyRent=sell&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=([^&]+)&Price= [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /%1/TimeshareForSale/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(testing/mypage.php)/TimeshareForSale/([^/]+)/?$ /$1?PropertyBuyRent=sell&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=$2&Price= [L,NC,QSA]
```

which works perfectly fine.. and redirects me to the above url i stated, but in my php file my variable no longer works which is $_GET['Country']  if i remove the htaccess it prints it fine.

Comment: This is your third question concerning URL rewriting within 4 hours now – how about you go read a tutorial on the matter first?

Comment: What do you mean by `if i remove the htaccess it prints it fine`?

Comment: if it doesnt rewrite url, it prints the variable fine

Comment: I just ran your code and got this query string `PropertyBuyRent=sell&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=US&Price=` You can see `$_GET['Country']` is there so it is probably due to some other rules in your .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine just the way u have it, u just need to change links for all your types, because you cant be using timeshare/us with all the conditions

Answer (score 0):

"I have the following url:"

"It changes the url like this:"

Whoa, whoa, whoa! You may be falling into the common trap of writing the .htaccess backwards.

```
http://site/testing/mypage.php/TimeshareForSale/US
```

is the "search engine friendly" *external* version of the URL. It will not work with your PHP code without first being converted (in .htaccess) to

```
http://site/testing/mypage.php?PropertyBuyRent=sell&Developer=&Resort=&City=&State=&Country=US&Price=
```

While this will work with or without an .htaccess URL rewrite, I presume you're trying to shield your users from it. .htaccess is for converting the first form into the second (inbound), not the other way around (outbound).

Now, in which direction are you trying to go?